# ODBC configuration to connect to Spark Thrift Server

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-thriftserver

This question might seem repeated, in fact, I've seen a couple of questions related to this but not exactly with the same error, so I'm asking to see if anyone has a clue.

I've set up a Spark Thrift Server running with default settings. Spark version is 2.1 and it runs on YARN (Hadoop 2.7.3)

The fact is that I'm not able to setup either the Simba hive ODBC driver nor the Microsoft one so that the Test in the ODBC setup succeeds.

This is the config I'm using for the Microsoft Hive ODBC driver:

[image]

When I hit the Test button, the error message shown is the following:

[image]

While in the Spark Thrift Server logs the following is seen:

```
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO ThriftCLIService: Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V1
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/00abf145-2928-4995-81f2-fea578280c42_resources
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/test/00abf145-2928-4995-81f2-fea578280c42
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/vagrant/00abf145-2928-4995-81f2-fea578280c42
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/test/00abf145-2928-4995-81f2-fea578280c42/_tmp_space.db
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO HiveSessionImpl: Operation log session directory is created: /tmp/vagrant/operation_logs/00abf145-2928-4995-81f2-fea578280c42
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query 'set -v' with 82d7f9a6-f2a6-4ebd-93bb-5c8da1611f84
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: set -v
17/09/15 17:31:36 INFO SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Result Schema: StructType(StructField(key,StringType,false), StructField(value,StringType,false), StructField(meaning,StringType,false))
```

If I connect using the JDBC driver by means of Beeline (which works ok), these are the logs:

```
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO ThriftCLIService: Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V8
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/test
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/c0681d6f-cc0f-40ae-970d-e3ea366aa414_resources
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/test/c0681d6f-cc0f-40ae-970d-e3ea366aa414
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/vagrant/c0681d6f-cc0f-40ae-970d-e3ea366aa414
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/test/c0681d6f-cc0f-40ae-970d-e3ea366aa414/_tmp_space.db
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO HiveSessionImpl: Operation log session directory is created: /tmp/vagrant/operation_logs/c0681d6f-cc0f-40ae-970d-e3ea366aa414
17/09/15 17:04:24 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: use default
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO HiveMetaStore: 1: get_database: default
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO audit: ugi=vagrant   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO HiveMetaStore: 1: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
17/09/15 17:04:25 INFO ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to connect successfully by installing the Microsoft Spark ODBC driver instead of the Hive one.
It looked like the problem had to do with the driver rejecting to connect to Spark Thrift Server when discovering it was not a Hive2 server based on some server property. I doubt there are actual differences at the wire level between Hive2 and Spark thrift server because the latter is a port of the former without changes at the protocol level (Thrift), but in any case, the solution is to move to this driver and configuring it the same way as the Hive2 one:

[Microsoft® Spark ODBC Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49883)

Comment: do you experienced any performance issue with above setting compared to http  option of thrift server to connect any BI tool(Power BI/tableau)?